# Kohana to PHP 7 Error

Tags: php, kohana, xenforo

Upgraded my PHP on server from 5.6 to 7.2 and now my website made on Kohana gives an error:

```
Declaration of Auth_Xenforo::logged_in() should be compatible with Kohana_Auth::logged_in($role = NULL)
```

Comment: You may need to update your vendor files too

Comment: What version of Kohana are you using? [Koseven](https://github.com/koseven/koseven) is a fork of Kohana which add support for PHP 7.

Answer (score 1):

Kohana is not PHP 7 ready. Please consider using it's PHP7 replacement (which will work as dropin, with small changes) koseven:

https://github.com/koseven/koseven